# sql with time interval, php and html: retrieve selected options after time interval is expired

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

I have the following table:

```
train
-------------
trainID
departuredate
```

For every passenger I have a form where they can choose 2 preferred dates from a dropdown list, but the options are limited: they only displays trains from the past 30 days or for future dates.
I then have an edit page where they can change the selected choices.

I load their previous choices from the database and put them in an array: $datesarray. Then output the 2 dropdowns

```
for ($i = 0; $i <2; $i++) {
  $sql = "SELECT trainID, departuredate
  FROM train
  WHERE departuredate > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY";

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  echo '<select name="train[]">';

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo '<option'
  , ($datesarray[$i] == $row['trainID'] ? ' selected="selected" ' : ' ' )
  . 'value="' . $row['trainID'] . '">'
  . $row['departuredate']
  . '</option>';
  } //end while
 echo '</select>';
}//end for
```

PROBLEM

When I load the edit form, if choices where made for trains before the past 30 days (of course) they wont show up in the options. 
I understand why this happens, but I don't know if there is a solution (in sql or php) to include the previuos choices, even if they refer to trains older than 30 days.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

That was easy!!!!
I just added OR to my query:

```
$sql = "SELECT trainID, departuredate
 FROM train
 WHERE departuredate > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30' DAY
 OR trainID = $datesarray[$i]";
```

PROBLEM 2

Now, I only have a problem if the  $datesarray[1] has no value. How could I modify my sql? Something like:

```
OR trainID = isset($datesarray[$i])";
```